# SecurityException when enumerating V1 tasks and displaying tasks' info using a DataGrid

Tags: c#-4.0, scheduled-tasks, codeplex, taskservice

I'm using [Task Scheduler Managed Wrapper from Codeplex](http://taskscheduler.codeplex.com/). I am facing a weird issue. I am trying to enumerate tasks in multiple remote servers (V1 and V2) and then display the tasks in a datagrid. This issue happens when I am connecting to a V1 server (using forceV1=true). The enumeration works fine - the data is passed to the grid even. But as soon as I move my cursor over the grid, I get a SecurityException saying 'Requested registry access is not allowed.' Does anyone know what's going on?

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  public MainWindow()
  {
    String osVer;
    using (var reg = RegistryKey.OpenRemoteBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, "deves07"))
    using (var key = reg.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\"))
    {
      osVer = string.Format("Name:{0}, Version:{1}", key.GetValue("ProductName"), key.GetValue("CurrentVersion"));
    }
    TaskService ts;
    if (osVer.Contains("2003"))
    {
      ts = new TaskService("REMOTE", "username", "domain", "password", true);
    }
    else
    {
      ts = new TaskService("REMOTE", "username", "domain", "password");
    }
    List<TaskInfo> taskList = new List<TaskInfo>();
    EnumFolderTasks(ts.RootFolder, taskList);
    DataContext = taskList;
  }

  void EnumFolderTasks(TaskFolder fld, List<TaskInfo> taskLst)
  {
    Debug.WriteLine(fld.Name);
    foreach (Task task in fld.Tasks)
      taskLst.Add(ActOnTask(task));
    foreach (TaskFolder sfld in fld.SubFolders)
      EnumFolderTasks(sfld, taskLst);
  }

  TaskInfo ActOnTask(Task t)
  {
    TaskInfo taskInfo = new TaskInfo();
    taskInfo.Name = t.Name;
    taskInfo.isRunning = t.IsActive;
    taskInfo.NextRunTime = t.NextRunTime;
    taskInfo.LastRunTime = t.LastRunTime;
    //taskInfo.LastRunStatus = t.LastTaskResult;
    return taskInfo;
  }

}

public class TaskInfo
{
  public string Name { set; get; }
  public bool isRunning { set; get; }
  public DateTime NextRunTime { set; get; }
  public DateTime LastRunTime { set; get; }
  public int LastRunStatus { set; get; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is courtesy of dahall over at codeplex (Thanks a lot dahall)

> First, try putting brackets in around the scope of your first `using`
>   statement. You can also do the same with the `TaskService` instance.
>   You could do this by doing:
>
> ```
> List<TaskInfo> taskList = new List<TaskInfo>();
> using (TaskService ts = new TaskService(REMOTE", "username", "domain", "password", osVer.Contains("2003")))
> {
>     EnumFolderTasks(ts.RootFolder, taskList);
> }
> DataContext = taskList;
> ```

I am not sure why this happens only for the V1 calls, but this did solve my problem.